# Is my HDD crashing?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, directx

I was playing this game named League of Legends today on my laptop. It is an MMOG and before the game started (the online fight between players) my laptop just hung and stopped responding. CTRL-ALT-DELETE didnt start the security options and the screen went plain black with  the cursor at the centre.
The OS then displayed a message that if the OS doesnt respond, use the power button to shut down the computer. And I did that because for the past two minutes it did not respond.
On booting it carried out a disk consistency check.
The HDD light stopped blinking; it was glowing bright all the time. The game was working well a couple of days ago and now I do not see the problem. It also displayed directX error even when I have dx11 Help!
What could be causing the computer to hang and what does the light indicate?

Comment: Other applications like Eclipse work well and good!

Comment: The hard drive light indicates activity. Blinking indicates random access while solidly lit would typically indicate constant access. Considering it was checking the drive, I would expect the drive light to be lit more, or solid, than what you normally see.

Comment: Not clear:  Did the computer ever successfully boot?  Your crash could have been due to a software error or a RAM memory error or an error on the I/O bus -- there's no real way to tell.

Comment: yes it boots successfully every time but when I open the game, it freezes. I will contact the vendor.

Comment: Based on your other questions and [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bpgqS.png), it sounds like what happened was that your system tried to read a file that is on a bad sector. This usually results in the system freezing because a hardware error will usually stop everything while it retries for a *while* until it times out and returns a software read-error. Worse, if it was a system-critical file, then the whole system may hang.

Comment: @Synetech it hangs for a while and then returns back to normal. Idea as to whats going on?>

Comment: It hangs for a while because the drive keeps retrying the read and eventually gives up and returns an error. You have to do a scan for bad sectors (`chkdsk /r`) to flag them so that they are not used (and eventually replace the drive).

Comment: @Synetech and what if the bad sector contained system files? Will they be migrated to new sectors?

Comment: Only if they can be read. If not, then you’ll have to restore it, which for system files is a good thing because they can be copied from the installation disc. Bad sectors in data files (those that *you created*) are much worse since you cannot restore them unless you happen to have a backup copy.

Comment: @Synetech so I should blindly `chkdsk /r` ?

Comment: It can’t hurt. It just scans for bad sectors and tries to copy any affected files to good sectors.

Comment: @Synetech is there anyway I can stay in contact with you outside SE?

Comment: Not generally/reliably, but there’s the chat function if you need it.

Comment: @Synetech not consistent. Also, what will be the size of my 132GB Drive's back up using DIXML? (Not in RAW mode)

Comment: It depends on if you [use compression](http://blog.brothersoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/using_driveimage_xml_to_backup_a_hard_drive_03.jpg) or not. It certainly won’t be any larger than 132GB.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a number of things. Is your HDD making weird noises when it's powered on? Like loud clicking or scraping noises? Or a very ritmic tick? The normal noise of the platters spinning around is good. When other noises appear (like that loud ticking and/or scraping), it usually is an indicator that your HDD is starting to fail.

Comment: I can hear a scraping sound if I push my ear against the laptop. At a normal distance, no!

Comment: If that sound is that quite, are you sure it's a scraping sound, and not just the platters spinning? If your PC freezes again, try listening for a ritmic tick, like the HDD is looking for something but can't get to it at exactly the same point every time it tries...

Comment: HP Support assistant says caondition is good